# Almacenar datos en lista y hacer cuentas con ellos sin base de datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Tengo un Recyclerview que muestra una lista de comidas, 
cada row del recyclerview tiene 2 botones , uno para cantidad de la comida y otro para disminuir cantidad de la comida , graficamente hay algo asi :

Coca-Cola   Precio : 10.00    -  0  +
Fanta       Precio : 8.00     -  0  +

Eso seria el Recyclerview 
Quiero que cada que la persona de al boton mas guarde la comida , 
la cantidad que han puesto actualmente y su precio.

Para despues pasarlo a cobrar mostrando un recibo.

Como guardar en tiempo real cada vez que la persona le da + a una comida
la comida, su cantidad y su precio.

Hasta ahora tengo esto

```
holder.botonMasComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.tvCantidadComida.setText("" + (cantidadComida = cantidadComida + 1));
            RestaurantDetalle.agregarComida(mealList.get(position).getName());
        }
    });
```

Activity

```
static public void agregarComida(String comida){

    listaComida.add(comida);

}
```

Comment: La elección de un modelo es elección tuya; por ejemplo una clase que represente a una persona, y dentro de una persona sus consumiciones. La gente de Java es tan amable que incluso tienes un montón de implementaciones de lista (`java.util.List`) para que uses la que te convenga más.

Comment: Podrías hacer una clase llamada bebida, en la cual tengas su nombre y precio y después haces una lista de bebidas.

Comment: @SJuan76 Por favor, chequen el editado.

Comment: @RandallSandoval Por favor, chequen el editado.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné asi :

```
static public void agregarComida(String comida) {
    listaComida.add(comida);
    hacerCuentasComida();
}

private static void hacerCuentasComida() {
    Map<String, Integer> contador = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> precio = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String item : listaComida) {
        String[] parts = item.split(",");

        if (!contador.containsKey(parts[0])) {
            duplicateList.add(parts[0]);
            contador.put(parts[0], 1);

            //Sacar precio
            precio.put(parts[0], Double.valueOf(parts[1]));
        } else {
            Integer count = contador.get(parts[0]);
            contador.put(parts[0], count + 1);
            count = contador.get(parts[0]);
            precio.put(parts[0], (count * Double.valueOf(parts[1])));
        }
    }

    Log.d("prueba1", String.valueOf(duplicateList));
    Log.d("prueba2", String.valueOf(contador));
    Log.d("prueba3", String.valueOf(precio));
    Log.d("textoCompleto", "x" + contador.get(duplicateList.get(0)) + " " + duplicateList.get(0) + " " + precio.get(duplicateList.get(0)) + "€");
}
```

Adapter :

```
holder.botonMasComida.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mealList.get(position).setCantidadComida(mealList.get(position).getCantidadComida() + 1);
        holder.tvCantidadComida.setText("" + mealList.get(position).getCantidadComida());
        RestaurantDetalle.agregarComida(mealList.get(position).getName() + "," + mealList.get(position).getPrice());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás debas realizar un **Array** de por ejemplo 100 posiciones en donde se irán guardando las coca-colas o fantas, ya después puedes realizar un **FOR** junto con un **IF** y una variable que trabaje como contador para buscar en cada posición cuantas coca-colas hay y así mismo paras las fantas :).

Comment: O bien hacer un **Array de Objetos** ahí si podrías agregar los atributos tipo de bebida y precio.